# Ignore java code from debug library

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

On my project I have a Stetho Library that I use just in debug compile. But when I try to generate a release apk, it returns an error when compile javacode saying that the Stetho library couldn`t be found.

**build.gradle**

```
//Stetho Library
debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.2.0'
debugCompile('com.parse:parseinterceptors:0.0.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts';
    exclude group: 'com.parse';
}
```

**StethoHelper.java**

```
public class StethoHelper {

  public static void initialize(Context context) {
    com.facebook.stetho.Stetho.initialize(
            com.facebook.stetho.Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(context)
                    .enableDumpapp(com.facebook.stetho.Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(context))
                    .enableWebKitInspector(com.facebook.stetho.Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(context))
                    .build());
  }

  public static void addInterceptor(Parse.Configuration.Builder builder) {
    builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new com.parse.interceptors.ParseStethoInterceptor());
  }
}
```

Ok, this error makes sense, but how can I suppress this error without have to comment my code?

Comment: did you try this libs compile 'com.parse:parseinterceptors:0.0.2' and compile 'com.parse:parseinterceptors:0.0.2' ?

Comment: @Javacoder Yeah, but I don`t want add an unnecessary lib on my release apk..

Comment: replace lib....

Comment: Its necessary when I debugging..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.2.0' which will work only for debug apk. you can change it to compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.2.0'.
though you should not enable stetho in release build for security reasons.
Here is simple documentation for your reference.
http://littlerobots.nl/blog/stetho-for-android-debug-builds-only/

Comment: Thanks for this reference, I will try this asap